# Getting error pjsip_eunsuptransport even set registrar with transport=tcp

Tags: android, sip, pjsip

I am getting error pjsip_eunsuptransport while receiving call from one mobile user. I set registrar with ;transport=tcp still this error is not resolved.

If anybody knows how to resolve this . Please let me know.

Its working fine with udp but want to create such connection with tcp.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure PJ_HAS_TCP is defined to 1 in config_site.h and sip_transport_tcp.c was not excluded from project.